# P5.js multiple canvases and one script with loadImage

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a problem placing multiple canvases in single html page with p5.js this is more complicated as its include importing images and procesing images.

```
var s1 = function(sketch) {
    let img, 
    sketch.colorFG = '#111111',
    sketch.colorBG = '#f1f1f1';

    function sketch.preload(){
    img = loadImage('https://picsum.photos/id/21/3008/2008'); //add an image
    }

    function sketch.setup() {
    sketch.createCanvas(600, 600);
    sketch.background(colorBG);
    img.resize(600, 600);
    }


    function sketch.draw() {
    sketch.background(colorBG);
    sketch.fill(colorFG);
    sketch.noStroke();
    const sketch.ratio = 600/600;
    let sketch.coefZ = (mouseX/width)*400;
    console.log(sketch.coefZ)
    console.log(sketch.mouseX)
    const sketch.tilesX = map(sketch.coefZ, 0, 600, 10, 100);
    const sketch.tilesY = ratio * sketch.tilesX;
    const sketch.tileSize = width / sketch.tilesX;
    for (let sketch.y = 0; y < img.height; sketch.y += sketch.tileSize) {
    for (let sketch.x = 0; x < img.width; sketch.x += sketch.tileSize) {
    let sketch.c = img.get(sketch.x, sketch.y);
    let sketch.b = map(brightness(sketch.c), 0, 255, 1, 0);
    push();
    translate(sketch.x, sketch.y);
    rect(0, 0, sketch.b * sketch.tileSize, sketch.b * sketch.tileSize);
    pop();
    }
    }
    }
};
new p5(s1);

var s2 = function(sketch) {
    let img2, 
    sketch.colorFG = '#111111',
    sketch.colorBG = '#f1f1f1';

    function sketch.preload(){
    img2 = loadImage('https://picsum.photos/id/22/4434/3729'); //add an image
    }

    function sketch.setup() {
    sketch.createCanvas(600, 600);
    sketch.background(colorBG);
    img2.resize(600, 600);
    }


    function sketch.draw() {
    sketch.background(colorBG);
    sketch.fill(colorFG);
    sketch.noStroke();
    const sketch.ratio = 600/600;
    let sketch.coefZ = (mouseX/width)*400;
    console.log(sketch.coefZ)
    console.log(sketch.mouseX)
    const sketch.tilesX = map(sketch.coefZ, 0, 600, 10, 100);
    const sketch.tilesY = ratio * sketch.tilesX;
    const sketch.tileSize = width / sketch.tilesX;
    for (let sketch.y = 0; y < img.height; sketch.y += sketch.tileSize) {
    for (let sketch.x = 0; x < img.width; sketch.x += sketch.tileSize) {
    let sketch.c = img2.get(sketch.x, sketch.y);
    let sketch.b = map(brightness(sketch.c), 0, 255, 1, 0);
    push();
    translate(sketch.x, sketch.y);
    rect(0, 0, sketch.b * sketch.tileSize, sketch.b * sketch.tileSize);
    pop();
    }
    }
    }
};
new p5(s2);
```

and html code for the website looks like this

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="column" id="s1">
      
</div>
    <div class="column" id="s2">
       </div>  
   
  </div>
```

I want both pictures to be rasterize and dsiplay on the webpage for now I have error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'sketch' has already been declared (at script.js:3:5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add in your HTML, specify which element should contain each sketch by setting the parent option when instantiating the sketch:

```js
new p5(sketch1, 'sketch1-container');
new p5(sketch2, 'sketch2-container');
```

This will create two separate canvas elements, each containing one of your sketches, and place them within the specified HTML elements.

eg: https://jsfiddle.net/x27w6jaf/3/

Comment: This is great solved my problem just added on element to fix mouse position when outside the canvas causing problems ```if (p.mouseX > 0 && p.mouseX < p.width && p.mouseY > 0 && p.mouseY< p.height) {p.coefZ = (p.mouseX / p.width) * 200;}```

Comment: And one more issue fixed that canvas was not instated when page open only when mouse was over the div. That because initial value for  p.coefZ was empty. So Just added  ```p.coefZ = 25``` and this work like a charm https://jsfiddle.net/4hf3rzx7/87/